# asp .net core 6 how to update option for json serialization. Date format in Json serialization

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-6.0

My apologies for the silly question, but I don't see a good example of how can I specify a specific format for DateTime in JSON serialization for .net core 6.

The old way, net core 3.

```
// in the ConfigureServices()
services.AddControllers()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
     {
         options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new DateTimeConverter());
     });
```

There is an example on the official website https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/system-text-json-support

```
JsonSerializerOptions options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
options.Converters.Add(new DateTimeConverterForCustomStandardFormatR());
```

"

But how can I wire it up to DI so It is used in the Controller?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

We can try to use [`builder.Services.Configure<JsonOptions>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/min-web-api?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#use-jsonoptions) to set our Serializer setting in DI container from .net core 6

`JsonOptions` let us configure JSON serialization settings, which might instead `AddJsonOptions` method.

`JsonOptions`might use same as `JsonOptions` object from DI in the [SourceCode](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/DependencyInjection/MvcCoreMvcBuilderExtensions.cs,50).

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Json;

builder.Services.Configure<JsonOptions>(options =>
{
    options.SerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new DateTimeConverterForCustomStandardFormatR());
});
```

I think this change is based on Microsoft wanting to introduce [minimal web API with ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/min-web-api?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) in .net 6

> Minimal APIs are architected to create HTTP APIs with minimal dependencies. They are ideal for microservices and apps that want to include only the minimum files, features, and dependencies in ASP.NET Core.

Comment: but how can I add [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull)] to builder.Services ... ?

Comment: How can I get a JsonOptions from the constructor of a Razor page model? The runtime can't resolve JsonOptions, neither IOptions<JsonOptions>.